# Flutter SQLlite the argument type 'Future<String>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' error

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, flutter

I have copied and modified a bit the code from this official tutorial: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/sqlite

My version of the insertion looks like this:

```
final Future<Database> database = openDatabase(
    join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'user_database.db'),
    onCreate: (db, version) {
      return db.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE users(uid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, display name TEXT, email TEXT)",
      );
    },
    version: 1,
  );
  Future<void> insertUser(User user) async {
  final Database db = await database;

  await db.insert(
    'users',
    user.toMap(),
    conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace,
  );

  final u = User("_displayName", "_email", "_ownerOfClub", "_password", "_id");

  await insertUser(u);
```

But it shows an error for the await getDatabasesPath() part: for the await it says: Unexpected text 'await', and for the getDatabasesPath(): The argument type 'Future' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this approach

```
Future<Database> database ;

void openDBFunction() async {
var databasesPath  = await getDatabasesPath();
String path = join(databasesPath, 'demo.db');

// open the database
    database = await openDatabase(path, version: 1,
    onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
  // When creating the db, create the table
  await db.execute(
      'CREATE TABLE Test (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, value INTEGER, num REAL)');
});
}
```

or

```
void openDBFunction() async {

// open the database
    database = await openDatabase(join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'demo.db'), version: 1,
    onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
  // When creating the db, create the table
  await db.execute(
      'CREATE TABLE Test (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, value INTEGER, num REAL)');
});
}
```

Comment: Now it gives an error for the await of the getDatabasesPath(), for the openDatabase and for the first argument of openDataBase() it says only static members can be accessed in initializers.

Comment: you need to nest it in an async function